# How to Pass HTML from Helper to ERB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in my .html.erb file that work just as expected:

```
<% if !current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in (or up)", '/login', :class => "login_button round" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign out", '/logout', :class => "login_button round" %>
<% end if %>
```

But I thought it would be nice to stick the conditional logic into the helper, and so clean up the .html.erb file.  I now have the following, but it does not work.  I the .html.erb:

```
<%= sign_in_out_button %>
```

And in the helper:

```
def sign_in_out_button
  out = ''
  if current_user
    out << link_to('Sign out', '/logout', :class => 'login_button round')
  else
    out << link_to('Sign in (or up)', '/login', :class => 'login_button round')
  end
end
```

What I do get, when inspecting the browser source code, is exactly what I'm looking for, but escaped so that it is displayed, instead of being interpreted by the browser as code.  Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails 3, the output code is escaped by default. You could do this:

```
def sign_in_out_button
  out = ''
  if current_user
    out << link_to('Sign out', '/logout', :class => 'login_button round')
  else
    out << link_to('Sign in (or up)', '/login', :class => 'login_button round')
  end
  out.html_safe
end
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  Does html_safe introduce any security concerns here (is that why the code gets escaped by default)?  Should I use some other way of doing it?

Comment: When output a variable of strings, especially from user inputs, there maybe some code you don't expected (such as a user type in `<script>alert(5201314)</script>`). In this case, you will get the alert box if you used `html_safe`, which trust all html codes! So for those not-carefully people, escape all codes by default protects from these kind of attacks (known as XSS, which could be sometimes serious).

Comment: In your case, all your codes are generated by your self, not from untrusted user, so you could just use `html_safe` without any worry. When you have to enable some tags for users, but you don't want them to use `<script>` etc, you should use `sanitize(html, options={})` instead, which is a helper method.